# Oracle Sorted Nested query and Exists optimization

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

[image]

```
SELECT *
    FROM price_t
    WHERE country = 'US'
    AND price_type     = 'SalesPrice'
    AND del_dtime     IS NULL
    AND item_no       IN
      (SELECT item_no
      FROM price_t a
      WHERE country = 'US'
      AND del_dtime     IS NULL
      AND EXISTS
        (SELECT *
        FROM price_t
        WHERE country         = a.country 
        AND price_type        = a.price_type
        AND currency_code     = a.currency_code
        AND item_no           = a.item_no
        AND ( from_dtime BETWEEN a.from_dtime AND a.to_dtime
        OR to_dtime BETWEEN a.from_dtime AND a.to_dtime
        OR (from_dtime    > a.from_dtime
        AND a.to_dtime   IS NULL)
        OR (from_dtime    < a.from_dtime
        AND to_dtime     IS NULL) )
        AND del_dtime    IS NULL
        AND NOT ( a.rowid = rowid )
        )
      )
    ORDER BY item_no, from_dtime;
```

The above query is taking 12 sec to give the response. Without order by 9 sec resonse. How to optimize it to give response in 2sec.

Comment: Show us the execution plan

Comment: @DaveCosta Execuiton plan attached.

Comment: It might help to create a text-formatted execution plan with plan statistics.  It's a bit harder to create but it produces more useful information.  First run `select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ * from ...`, then find the `SQL_ID` with `select * from gv$sql where sql_text like '%gather_plan_statistics%';`, and then generate the execution plan with `select * from table (dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id => 'your SQL_ID', format=>'ALLSTATS LAST'));`.

Comment: Also, how many rows does this query return?  If there's a large number of results, and the input tables are large, there's not always a trivial way to make it run faster; memory can only hold so much data, and disks can only spin so fast.

Comment: I guess rather than posting your query, You might share the problem with us. We will try our level best to provide you  the best optimal solution.